# Function synchronization and observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, synchronized

I have a Typescript function which converts a list of elements into a Map: Map.

Along this process of conversion, I need to modify something in the Map before returning the Map.
To obtain the info, I have to request a server so I have a http.GET request/subscription to get the value.

I am using the value right after the GET, and the server has not yet answer, so I am returning the Map with the wrong value.
(It comes later but too late).

Then I use this map in which I don't have the correct value

I need a mechanism to synchronize my function with the result of my GET request, before processing the Map later in my code (after returning the function).

How can I do this, I have been told that the Observable may be the solution, but I don't know how to do it.

I could use some help ;-).

Best regards,
Charles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do this, I have been told that the Observable may be the solution, but I don't know how to do it.

For async things you need some form of *continuation* mechanism. The popular choices are:

### Callbacks

Supported natively e.g. `setTimeout` uses it

```
// Some code 

setTimeout(() => {
  // Some more code that executes after 1 second
}, 1000)
```

### Promises

Supported natively (now). Some docs on TypeScript and how they help https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html

### Observables

If your frameworks *http* returns observables you would need to use them.

## Summary

You cannot halt execution of *entire* JavaScript as JavaScript's JS context is single threaded. You need to work with continuations. Check the docs of the library (e.g. angular / axios) or native api (fetch / XHR) you are using.

Comment: The Observable is definitively what I need, I encountered other problems as I try to implement my solution and as it is related to another subject, I will open another thread of discussion. Thank you for your help.